# Unable to get keys values from an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I use this code to execute Axios and save it in `myObject` variable:

```
const myObject = {}
Object.entries(keysParameter).map((entry, index) => { 
 axios
  .get(url)
  .then((res) => {                
     myObject[entry[1].value] = res.data.data
  });
})
```

When I do `console.log(myObject)`

the outcome is as expected:

```
{
  "A": [
        "",
        "AA",
        "BB",
       ],
  "B": [
        "AA",
        "BB",
       ]
}
```

But when I do `console.log(Object.keys(myObject))` the outcome is an empty array `[]`.

And when I run myObject.hasOwnProperty("A") the outcome is `false`.

And when I do `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)))` the outcome is `{} [[Prototype]]: Object`

Anyone knows why? I'm simply expecting `["A", "B"]`?

Comment: When and how do you define `myObject`? Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: I found no error of your code. Are you get this object from api and this object is a empty  array?

Comment: I just edited my question with additional information about myObject. Thanks.

Comment: `axios` is asynchronous, so it really depends on WHEN you `console.log(Object.keys(myObject))` ... where as, `console.log(myObject)` will seem to show the right thing, because it is evaluated when you inspect it in the console, and by then, presumably, the axios stuff has done its work

Comment: also, why are you using `.map` when you don't care about the result of the `.map` (which would be undefined anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX, I've tested using time:
 setTimeout(() => {console.log(Object.keys(searchFilter))}, 100) 
The result still the same === **[]**. I run console.log(myObject) before and after I run console.log(Object.keys(myObject)).


And I use .map as the **keysParameter** is a JSON object.

Comment: try a LONGER timeout - you're using `.map` exactly like it's `.forEach` ... which is why I asked why bother with `.map` if you don't care what the callback returns - though, ironically, using `.map` can be the solution, see the posted answer

Answer (score 1):

When you `console.log` things, the contents are loaded generally when you expand the object, otherwise whenever your browser feels like it. If you want to get the exact state of an object at a current point, you can generally do `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)))`.

What's happening here is a data race of sorts, since you're trying to access the data before the axios get calls are completed.

You need to wrap this in `Promise.all` and use `await` to make sure to wait until the data is loaded. (You need to either add `return` or change it to just simplicity return the `.then` call, like i have done)

```js
const myObject = {}
await Promise.all(Object.entries(keysParameter).map((entry, index) => 
 axios
  .get(url)
  .then((res) => {                
     myObject[entry[1].value] = res.data.data
  })
));

console.log(Object.keys(myObject));
```

If you're not already in an `async` function or the top level of an ES module, you can't use `await`, so you need to either change it to an `async` function or use `.then` after the `Promise.all(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea on how to resolving this issue. I rearranged my methods as my code combination between class based functions and react's hook. Now I can move on to the next function.